# Twitter bootstrap modal doesn't allow a javascript email capture form?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and the modal works great (pop-up).

What I am trying to do is embed a simple one line of javascript into the modal, so the pop-up is an email capture form. Should be simple stuff and Chrome likes it, as does IE, but Firefox (20.0.1) just draws a blank. The modal appears but no javascript email capture.

Here is the one line of javascript I am trying to place within the modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ool88222.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/0bb1dd5ff343dd6d7845eb723"></script>
```

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/listerdl/DYcv6/) but it doesnt work there, I think it also needs jquery?

The below is the modal:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas what or how I might have to do to get the single line of javascript (i.e. email capture form) to just be allowed to work within the modal (in Firefox)?

Comment: DO you want to insert it dynamcially on to the modal when it is opened?

Comment: Hey thanks! Yes I do - the one line of javascript is just a really simple email form - so the user simply enters their email and their is a submit button - that's it.

Id like that one line of javascript to do its job in the actual modal. Chrome and IE is fine - firefox just ignores it and I cant figure out what I can do to solve this....

Thanks again for having replied

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your referencing jQuery and JQuery UI.

New fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/DYcv6/6/

```
    <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>

<ul id="tweets"> 
</ul>
```

Close
    Save changes